# Avoiding subselect when using MAX()

Tags: sql, db2

Is there a way I can avoid this sub-select?
I am trying to make this query as efficient as possible, and in doing so, trying to avoid a sub-select.

I am looking for the most recent replaced rows on a table by ID_NUM.

The sub-select is in place so that I ONLY bring back the most recently replaced row. Is this the best way to do that?

The query works perfectly the way I want it to, so feel free to ignore up to the last little sub-select.

```
SELECT   
  A.ID_NUM,
  A.DOB,
  A.NAME,
  A.REPLACED_TMESTMP  
FROM MYTABLE A, MYTABLE B  
WHERE   
  A.ID_NUM = B.ID_NUM
  AND A.REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NOT NULL
  AND B.REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NULL
  AND A.DOB <> B.DOB
  several other conditions...

  AND A.REPLACED_TMESTMP  
    = (SELECT MAX(C.REPLACED_TMESTMP)  
      FROM MYTABLE C  
      WHERE C.ID_NUM = A.ID_NUM  
      AND A.REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NOT NULL  
      )
;
```

Here's some pseudo code to help you understand what i need to do

```
Select all from table
where a duplicate ID number exists
    that has an active row (no replaced time stamp)
    and has an inactive row(s)
    only bring back the most current replaced row for each ID num.
```

Comment: Which version of DB2?  Don't use the 'implicit-join' (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax, it's considered an SQL anti-pattern (it does okay for regular joins, but starts showing 'odd' behavior for `LEFT` and others).  You don't need to re-check `A.Replaced_Timestamp` in the subquery.  Don't suffix/prefix columns with datatypes, it's noise; use a better descriptive name (ie `replacedAt`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could re-write the sub-select as a `JOIN`.  We have a similar setup on one of our tables here at work (where we have multiple "rows" for each "thing", but you only ever deal with the "newest" one), and I ran a sub-select type query and a `JOIN` type through Visual Explain, and according to the estimate, the `JOIN` would take quite a lot less CPU seconds to process (of course, this is only an estimate, and your table is likely much different than mine, so take this with a grain of salt).

I changed up the query a bit, I think this should have all the information you're looking for.

```
SELECT INACTIVE.ID_NUM
      ,INACTIVE.DOB
      ,INACTIVE.NAME,
      ,INACTIVE.REPLACED_TMESTMP  
FROM (
    SELECT *
    FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NULL
) AS ACTIVE
JOIN (
    SELECT *
    FROM MYTABLE
    WHERE REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NOT NULL
) AS INACTIVE
  ON ACTIVE.ID_NUM = INACTIVE.ID_NUM
 AND ACTIVE.DOB   <> INACTIVE.DOB
  -- several other conditions...

JOIN (
    SELECT ID_NUM,
           MAX(REPLACED_TMESTMP) AS TIMESTAMP
    FROM MYTABLE
    GROUP BY ID_NUM
) MAX_REPLACE
  ON INACTIVE.ID_NUM           = MAX_REPLACE.ID_NUM
 AND INACTIVE.REPLACED_TMESTMP = MAX_REPLACE.TIMESTAMP
```

Comment: +1 - The other generally viable option, although you're still dealing with a _mental_ equivalent to a subquery, in some ways.  Personally I'd probably write some of this up using CTEs, but the optimizer should remove the differences.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   
  A.ID_NUM,  
  MAX(A.REPLACED_TMESTMP) AS MOST_RECENT_REPLACED_ROW
FROM MYTABLE A,
     MYTABLE B
WHERE   
    A.ID_NUM = B.ID_NUM
    AND A.REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NOT NULL
    AND B.REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NULL
GROUP BY A.ID_NUM
;
```

Comment: I don't think this works with my query. I've added some pseudo code to help people see what I'm doing a little better.

Comment: I added the self join with B and the where clause from your original code. Does that look like it will work? If not, would you provide sample data that would not produce the result you expect?

Comment: That statement works, until I begin adding more of the table columns in to the select clause. It's weird... All of the where conditions work fine. But when I start adding more table columns in the select. It complains. I'll see what I can do.

Comment: because I'm looking at A and B, I don't think the `group by` will work. I get SQL error code 122. Reading in to it, i think that's why.

Comment: Regardless, I think you did answer the question on how to avoid a sub-select. I just don't think it's possible to do it with the query I have to write.

Comment: 2 things - 1) You're using the 'implicit-join' (comma-separated `FROM` clause) syntax, which is generally considered an SQL antipattern (not so bad with straight joins, but `LEFT` ones can have odd behavior).  2) This will not work if additional (non-`GROUP`ed, or not aggregateable) columns are needed.

Answer (score 1):

If your version of DB2 supports the `ROW_NUMBER()` function, you could do something like this:

```
WITH ranked AS (
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
      PARTITION BY replaced.ID_NUM
      ORDER BY replaced.REPLACED_TMESTMP DESC
    ) AS rnk.
    replaced.ID_NUM,
    replaced.REPLACED_TMESTMP,
    replaced.... /* other columns as necessary */
  FROM MYTABLE replaced
    INNER JOIN MYTABLE active ON replaced.ID_NUM = active.ID_NUM
  WHERE replaced.REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NOT NULL
    AND active.REPLACED_TMESTMP IS NULL
    AND ... /* your other conditions */
)
SELECT
  ID_NUM,
  REPLACED_TMESTMP,
  ...
FROM ranked
WHERE rnk = 1
;
```

The `ROW_NUMBER()` function assigns numbers to rows where `REPLACED_TMESTMP` is not null in the descending order of that column, partitioning by `ID_NUM`. The main SELECT then simply retrieves rows ranked as `1`.

Comment: I see. I tried this. It appears my version does not like ROW_NUMBER() The error code returned a problem right at that word. TY though.